# Finding all the regions in a webpage's image

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection, image-segmentation

I am working on a project where I need to find different regions present in an image(for any web page) like - navigation bar, menu bar, body, advertisement section etc. First I want to segment my entire image into distinct regions/sections using Image processing.

What I have done:
1st approach: I ran edge detection algorithm(Canny), this way I could see different regions in the form of rectangular boxes. However, I couldn't find a way to recognize all these regions.

2nd approach: I dealt with Hough transform to get all the horizontal and vertical lines which can help me in deciding different rectangular sections in the image. However, I am not able to come up with some  concrete approach to use this houghlines to find all the rectangular regions imbibed in the image.

Any kind of your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: You don't need to use Hough transforms on screen grabs, as the edges should all be perfectly horizontal or vertical anyway. But I think it would be much easier to label the page regions based on the raw HTML and CSS than to second-guess their significance based on image data alone. Can you provide some example of the sort of images/web pages you're trying to process?

Comment: Here is one of the sample pages which I am trying to process: http://www.csdl.tamu.edu/~shipman/

Comment: If you have the page URLs, then you should abandon this idea of determining the page structure from screen grabs. You will find it *far* easier to figure out the page structure by analysing the HTML with, for example, a set of [Bayesian classifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_Classifiers). The page you linked to has four blocks with classnames of `header`, `left`, `content` and `footer`. This information alone will get you half way to a solution. Use other information like the link-to-text ratio and use of sentence punctuation (commas, full stops, etc.) to refine your results.

Comment: Did you tried to google [link1](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/70027/tr-2003-79.pdf) [link2](http://www.cad.zju.edu.cn/home/dengcai/VIPS/VIPS.html) it? I hope that I have understand you:)

Comment: I think I should have mentioned it earlier. I am well aware of VIPS. However, this project demands me to do things using Image processing. I should not be indulged in any tag based implementation(this is what my prof wants).

Comment: I need to take the screenshot of the webpage(which I have taken) and then do whatever I can do on top of that image. Hope I made myself clear.